# Find pairs in an array (c)

Tags: c

Hello is there any way to find a 2 or 3 same numbers on a user inputted int array?

For example if a user entered the numbers: 1 1 3 2 6. 
The output will say 1 1 are the same

Another example is if a user entered the numbers: 2 2 2 3 4. 
The output will say 2 2 2 are the same

I know that this is one way to find a pair/duplicate in an array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) 
{

    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) 
        {
            printf("There's a duplicate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more what should the output be? For example consider an array { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 }.

Comment: Your code looks like it works. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What kind of output for cases like {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2} ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow so my code only accept 5 numbers from the user. For my code my output displays the user entered number and the sentence "There's a duplicate"

Comment: @usr2564301 it works but I also want it to display what the same numbers are, and that's where I'm stuck on how to do that.

Comment: @neutrino_logic so my input only accepts 5 numbers. For a case like {1, 1, 1, 2, 2} I'd like my output to say: There are 3 number 1 and 2 number 2.

Comment: @Syked You can [edit] your question to clarify it. Also, concentrate on only one aspect of a problem. Do you want to find all pairs of duplicate elements? Do you want to find all sets of identical elements of any size, or only 2 and 3? Do you want to format your output in a natural language? Pick one aspect which is most important to you, otherwise you will get answers which are too long, incorrect, or too complicated. Or none at all, if the question is unclear. You might also want to consider this: [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I  wrote a quick and dirty function to check for all duplicates of a certain value:

```
void
find_duplicates( int find, size_t len, const int orig[])
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ )
  {
    if( orig[i] == find)
    {
      printf(“Duplicate at; %d\n”, i);
    }
  }
}
```